# Python: Approximating ln(x) using Taylor Series

Tags: python, numerical-integration, taylor-series

I'm trying to build an approximation for ln(1.9) within ten digits of accuracy (so .641853861).

I'm using a simple function I've built from ln[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]

Here is my code so far:

```
# function for ln[(1 + x)/(1 - x)]

def taylor_two(r, n):
    x = 0.9 / 2.9
    i = 1
    taySum = 0
    while i <= n:
        taySum += (pow(x,i))/(i)
        i += 2
    return 2 * taySum

print taylor_two(x, 12)

print taylor_two(x, 17)
```

What I need to do now is reformat this so that it tells me the number of terms needed to approximate ln(1.9) to the above 10 digits, have it display the value that series gives, and also show the error.

I assume I need to build my function into a for loop somehow, but how can I get it to stop iterating once it's reached the 10 digits needed?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Note that "r" used in the function definition is never used.  Also there will be an error on both of the "print taylor_two(x, 12)" lines because x has not been declared.  To return from the function before all n tries, you have to submit a lower (and maybe upper) number(s) to compare the calculated numbers to if .6418538 < taySum*2 < .6418539: for example.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your comment. I see now that there's a problem with x not being declared. Could you give a coded example of what you mean about lower and upper numbers? I'm not sure what you mean here.

Comment: I put an if statement in the previous post.  Floating point numbers may not be 100% accurate so you have to define "equals" as a lower and upper number, and anything in between is "equal"

Answer (score 5):

The principle is;

- Look at how much each iteration adds to the result.
- Stop when the difference is smaller than 1e-10.

You're using the following formula, right;

[image: ln formula]

(Note the validity range!)

```
def taylor_two():
    x = 1.9 - 1
    i = 1
    taySum = 0
    while True:
        addition = pow(-1,i+1)*pow(x,i)/i
        if abs(addition) < 1e-10:
            break
        taySum += addition
        # print('value: {}, addition: {}'.format(taySum, addition))
        i += 1
    return taySum
```

Test:

```
In [2]: print(taylor_two())
0.6418538862240631

In [3]: print('{:.10f}'.format(taylor_two()))
0.6418538862
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Roland. I'm actually using 2*sum k=1 to infinity for (x^(2k - 1))/(2k - 1) to approximate. I've tried your code, and it's not quite what I'm looking to do. Maybe I phrased the questions wrong. I need the system to work up to the value required & stop once it's within 10 digits accuracy, then have it give me that value. The code you gave requires me to input values myself. Does that make sense?

Comment: I assume a need some sort of while loop that iterates until the difference between ln(1.9) and the resulting value is very small. I'm just not sure how do build this.

Comment: @BigD4J See updated answer. The algorithm runs until the addition from the next step is <1e-10. If you want to see how it works, uncomment the `print()` in the loop.