# Python: Calculating Error of Taylor Series

Tags: python, numerical-integration, taylor-series

I'm trying to calculate the error for the Taylor series I've calculated with the following code:

```
# Define initial values, including appropriate value of x for the series input
import numpy as np
x = -0.9
i = 1
taySum = 0
ln = np.log(1.9)
terms = 1

''' Iterate through the series while checking that 
the difference between the obtained series value and ln(1.9) 
exceeds 10 digits of accuracy. Stop iterating once the series 
value is within 10 digit accuracy of ln(1.9).'''

while (abs(taySum - ln) > 0.5e-10) == True:
       taySum += (-1) * (pow(x,i))/(i)
       i += 1
       terms += 1
print ('value: {}, terms: {}'.format(taySum, terms))
```

I need to somehow incorporate the error function which calculates the kth derivative and I'm not sure how to do this. The error formula is available [at this website](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/calculus/remainder-term/remainder-term.html) which is the following:

[image: $$R_n(x; c) = \dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(z)}{(n + 1)!} (x - c)^{n+1}.$$]

Comment: Can you add the mathematical formula or a description of the method to your question? I'm not familiar with the math behind this and I'm sure I can't be the only one on the Python tag.

Comment: Sure. What I've done is attempted to calculate ln(1.9) through the following Taylor series: ln(1 - x) = (-1)*Sum ((x^k)/k)) from k =1 to infinity. I then needed to stop after the number of terms reach within ten digits accuracy of ln(1.9).

Here is the remainder (error) formula I need to use: http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/calculus/remainder-term/remainder-term.html. I'm not sure how to type this into Stack Overflow.

Comment: I edited in an image for the formula, please roll back my edit if I have included the wrong thing here.

Comment: Your question would be greatly improved if you could let us know how you wish to use the error term, what problem are you trying to solve with this? Are you able to pre-compute the general form of the derivative, as in before you write any code? Or do you require a derivative to be calculated at runtime? A few other comments, you don't need variables `i` and `terms` they are the same thing. Also you can just do `while abs(taySum - ln) > 0.5e-10` because the comparison vs true is unnecessary.

Comment: @shuttle87 Good call on the image. Did you take a look at the OP's [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235707/python-approximating-lnx-using-taylor-series)? It might give you a bit more of the background you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to calculate the error in a taylor series exactly unless you know the exact value it is converging to, which for something like ln 1.9 we don't. The formula you have quoted gives the error in terms of a quantity c < z < x (assuming c < x), which in this case is in the range 0 < z < 0.9, but is otherwise unknown. This means we cannot use this use formula to find the exact error. (otherwise we could find the exact value of ln 1.9, which is not possible)

What this formula does is put bounds on the error. If you look at the formula you will see it has the same form as the next term in the series with the argument of f^(n+1) changed from c, the point you are expanding around, to z, our unknown parameter.  In other words it is saying that the error is approximately the same size as the next term in the series, or at least it will if the parameter you are expanding in is small.

With this in mind I would approximate the error by simply computing the next term in the series and saying it is basically that.